# git branch names local vs remote tracking

Tags: git, branch

I use git 1.8.3.2.

I use a bare "w1.git" repository to test git related things.

I did the following

```
 git clone -- file:///home/rohloff/git/w1.git w1_clone
```

So now I have got the following branches (leaving out SHA1 and commit messages):

```
 git branch -avv

 master                   [origin/master]
 remotes/origin/HEAD      -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/master
```

So now I did

```
 git branch origin/master
```

and to my complete surprise that works ?!

I now have got

```
git branch -avv

master                 [remotes/origin/master]
origin/master
remotes/origin/HEAD    -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
```

Note how "master" now cleverly points to "remotes/origin/master".

But if I try to now create a topic branch with

```
git branch topic origin/master
```

I get (not surprisingly)

```
Warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous.
```

So I am wondering:

- Is there any way to tell git to forbid the creation of "ambiguous" branches ? Or is it simply my responsibilty to avoid creating such ambiguously named branches ?
- With the "git branch topic" above: Is there any way to clearly specify which branch I mean ?

**EDIT** : It turns out the following is also allowed:

```
 git branch origin/master
 git branch remotes/origin/master
 git branch refs/remotes/origin/master
```

After these three commands it seems there is no way at all anymore to refer to "master" from the "origin" remote repository...

**EDIT** : It turns out this problem is right now (15 Feb 2014) discussed on the git developer mailing list. see

https://marc.info/?t=139237924400005&r=1&w=2

The proposal is to forbid something like this as long as someone does not use "-f".

Comment: Incidentally, git stores the branch names "fully resolved" internally and merely abbreviates them on output, hence the cleverness whereby master apparently tracks "origin/master" until it needs to track "remotes/origin/master".  Internally it's tracking "refs/remotes/origin/master". :-)

Comment: Yes. But "git branch refs/remotes/origin/master" *also* works...

Comment: Hm, perhaps git should refuse local branches whose name starts with `refs/`...

Comment: @torek: Yes, this seems like a reasonable idea to me... Maybe actually forbid any branch names with refs/... remotes/... heads/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I don't believe there is a built-in way to prevent creation of ambiguous branches. And even if there was such an option to `git branch`, if you create a local branch origin/foo when there's no remotes/origin/foo that's something that might change over time.
- Yes, you can specify the fully-qualified names, i.e. refs/heads/origin/master and refs/remotes/origin/master. In fact, you can drop the initial "refs/" as e.g. heads/origin/master is unambiguous.

Comment: The problem is I can also do "git branch refs/remotes/origin/master" . It seems git has no constraints on branch name whatsoever :-(. I guess it is possible (by being "unconventional" ;-)) to create several local branches so that in the end you are not able to address your remote branch at all...